# Animations within Canvas are not working

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

I have a weird problem with my animations. No matter what, I cannot get anything to move. I have even made a simple code to see what the problem is, but all I am getting is a static square which does nothing. I have tried with Chrome, IE, and Edge, and all of them give the same result.
Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> K: The Potassium Struggle </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="370"></canvas>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScripts/one.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's the JavaScript:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var x = canvas.width/2;
var y = canvas.height-30
var dx = 2;
var dy = -2;

function character () {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(20, 40, 50, 50);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#912CEE";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}

function draw () {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
    character();
    x += dx;
    y += dy;
}

setInterval(draw, 10);
```

Any ideas why things aren't moving??

Comment: You don't use the `x` and `y` values in the character function. So it draws it always on the fixed values. `ctx.rect(x, y, 50, 50);`will draw it with the changing values...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are always drawing your rect at a fixed location [20,40] rather than letting [x,y] reposition your rect.

Here's refactored code:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var x = canvas.width/2;
var y = canvas.height-60
var dx = .1;
var dy = -.1;

function character () {
    ctx.beginPath();
    // ctx.rect(20, 40, 50, 50);
    ctx.rect(x,y, 50, 50);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#912CEE";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}

function draw () {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
    character();
    x += dx;
    y += dy;
}

setInterval(draw, 10);
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width=200 height=200></canvas>
```